# C#: How to create a mock Azure.AI.OpenAI.ChatCompletions object to test functions using OpenAI?

Tags: c#, openai-api, azure-openai, azure-ai

I have a simple function that takes a prompt, sends it to a model on our Azure OpenAI instance, and returns the content of the LLM's response:

```cs
        public async Task<string> GetChatCompletion(string deploymentName, ChatCompletionsOptions conversation)
        {
            // `client` is of type `Azure.AI.OpenAI.OpenAIClient`
            var response = await client.GetChatCompletionsAsync(deploymentName, conversation).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return response.Value.Choices[0].Message.Content;
        }
```

I'd like to write tests for this function (or similar ones), but I can't figure out how to create a mock object for the return value of `client.GetChatCompletionsAsync`. It's of type `Azure.AI.OpenAI.ChatCompletions`, but I don't see any constructor or publicized way to create a mock object of this type. Thanks in advance.

`new ChatCompletions()` doesn't exist, there doesn't seem to be a clear `ChatCompletions.FromX(...)` function either. Searching online has given no clear results as everything is populated with tutorials for how to get real data.

Comment: The code is sending a HTTP request and returning an HTTP response (the variable response).  The response will have headers and a body.  I would put a break point on last line of code and examine the variable "response" and see what it contains.  I NEVER use var as a type unless I have to because of situation like this.  You cannot tell what is bein returned from client.GetChatCompletionsAsync() method.

Comment: I know what's being returned: A Response<ChatCompletions> object. The problem is how to create a mock ChatCompletions object :)

Comment: The response body is a serialize ChatCompletions class.  The serialization could be binary or JSON.  One way is to create a loopback route that would take the body of the request and loopback to the body of the response.  Or a test method that would emulate the response body.

Comment: Gotcha, so the best way you see would just be `JsonConverter.Deserialize<ChatCompletions>(mockChatString)`?

Comment: The deserialize method has to be compatible with the serialize method on the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using AzureOpenAIModelFactory to mock all OpenAIClient response types, see: [AzureOpenAIModelFactory.ChatCompletions Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.ai.openai.azureopenaimodelfactory.chatcompletions?view=azure-dotnet-preview)

```
     var choices = new List<ChatChoice>
    {
        AzureOpenAIModelFactory.ChatChoice(message: new ChatMessage(ChatRole.Assistant, "Foobar"), index: 0, finishReason: CompletionsFinishReason.Stopped),
        AzureOpenAIModelFactory.ChatChoice(message: new ChatMessage(ChatRole.Assistant, "Bazbar"), index: 1, finishReason: CompletionsFinishReason.Stopped)
    };

    var chatCompletions = AzureOpenAIModelFactory.ChatCompletions(null, default, choices, null, null);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Probably due to changes in the OpenAi SDK, but I found it helpful to use this method to generate the messages: `AzureOpenAIModelFactory.ChatResponseMessage(...)`